# Is there an html tag that does not have any effect on an html document?

Tags: html, tags

In html, is there a tag that I can add an id attribute to, that does not have any effect on the html page, but can still be accessed with a jQuery selector?

Here is an example:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
```

If I have the above code in a list, what tag can I add to this html, so that I can then use jQuery to perform actions on the code items as children?

The above code is just an example, I am wanting to be able to use this technique for any html element.

**EDIT**

Is the `<span>` tag what I am looking for?

**EDIT2**

I have tried the following with a span tag:

```
<span id="qwerty123"><li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li></span>
```

However, the list items are not being displayed correctly. I am using an AdminLTE template and this template uses custom styling for these list items.

How else can I achieve the desired result? Can I add data attributes or some other html coding technique?

**EDIT3**

The html tag with the id needs to be before any of the other tags, so that all the rest of the tags can be treated as children.

Comment: Add an ID to your span

Comment: @zavtra: no, he didn't. Look at the last tag on the line

Answer (score 12):

The `span` tag is indeed what you are looking for: it's the only HTML inline container tag. Unless you apply CSS to it, it's simply an inline tag that doesn't alter the way your document is displayed.

[Read this for more details: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)

Please also note that you could use a `div` tag and apply CSS `display:inline;` to achieve the same result.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: w3schools has a very bad reputation. You'd do better to provide links to the [actual standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). Note that w3schools has nothing to do with the w3c, which is the standards organization responsible for HTML.

Comment: Thank you @JohnSaunders for your suggestion. I was simply giving a link to a web page that spoke an easier language than the official documentation, but I see your point. I have indeed edited my answer to include the span tag W3C reference. Did you flag it as not useful because of the link? Well then, you may now flag it as useful ;)

Comment: It doesn't matter how easy w3schools is to understand, if it's wrong. If you want something written a little less in standardeze, try [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

Comment: The problem with SPAN is that adding it makes the HTML pick up (or drop) different CSS rules and by that changes the layout.

Comment: An example of SPAN changing the color of the text: https://jsfiddle.net/02da4kt8/

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
<li>
    <span id="targetSpan" style="display:none;">
        <!-- any children -->
    </span>
    <a href="#">
        <i class='fa fa-link'></i> 
        <span>Another Link</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

In a block context, you can do the same with "`div`":

```
<div id="targetDiv" style="display:none;">
    <!-- any children -->
</div>
```

I don't believe you can use a `div` within the `li`, however.

Comment: Is there an html tag that has no effect at all on any html elements?

Comment: Is the span tag what I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, the `span` tag. That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You could include an element and then make it invisible. For instance: `<i></i>` or `<em></em>` and then set

```
i {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And then add an ID and select that element. The element won't affect anything on the page, but will still be capable of being selected.

Answer (score 0):

**try to use Unique ID selector** like

`<li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span id="id7843">Another Link</span></a></li>`

in this id `(id="id7843")`  **you can use your id according to your need**

your can define class or fuction for that id in jquery it does not affect any other html **unless if you are having same id**.. **try to use unique id for every class you defined.**

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about. He wants a tag in the DOM that he can reference via jQuery, but which will not affect the appearance of the document.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. thanks for the comment to clear understand the question..

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span id = "putyouridhere">Another Link</span></a></li>
```